# ¿Para qué sirve el console.log()?

Tags: javascript, web

Sé que imprime texto en consola para confirmar la operatividad del javascript, pero tiene otra utilidad? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

justamente como su nombre lo dice, sirve para enviar un log al consola, es decir no solo texto, dependiendo de que consola puedes imprimir por ejemplo objetos y verlos como en las consolas de navegadores.

[Aquí tienes mas información sobre console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log)

En la misma página puedes ver que console tiene más métodos, estos los puedes usar dependiendo de que sea lo que necesites imprimir y como lo necesites imprimir, por ejemplo yo uso mucho console.error() para imprimir los errores y visualizarlos mejor.